# Adding array values to table while fetching part of values from database error

Tags: php, mysql

I have retrieved three rows from the mysql database. In one row, there is a name, address. I have hard-coded the age in an array, which is in order of the name displayed in the table, so that the age corresponds to a name. Now I want to each age to appear in the same row that corresponds to the name. How can I achieve this below?

```
$info = array('12', '55', '95');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Address'].'</td>';

    foreach($info as $age){
        echo '<td>' . $age . '</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use, for example, array_shift function to take items of the array in the loop

```
$info = array('12', '55', '95');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Address'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>' . array_shift($info) . '</td>';
}
```